# Multinomial test in Python with met module

Tags: python-3.x, multinomial, statistical-test

I am trying to conduct a multinomial test in Python --the analogous in R would be:

```
library(XNomial)
xmulti(prfs, c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), statName="Prob")
```

I am using the met module.  However I get an exception.  Here is the code:

```
prfs
    Pref
A   8
B   21
C   31

import met
met.twosided_exact_likelihood(ref_obs = [1/3, 1/3, 1/3], site_obs = prfs.Pref/prfs.Pref.sum())

AttributeError: module 'met' has no attribute 'twosided_exact_likelihood'
```

Answer (score 3):

This late reply may be moot, but somebody just notified me of this question.  I'm the author of the `met` module.  Evidently the latest version was lost from PyPI at some point, perhaps during the transition to the new warehouse.  I have just re-uploaded the latest code and a little additional documentation.